# Xamarin.Forms.Map show PIns from Command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

```
public partial class ClientMap: ContentPage
   {
ClientCoordinateviewModel viewModel= new ClientCoordinateviewModel ();
       Client client;
       public ClientMap(Client selected_client)
       {
           Title = klient.Select_client_name;
           InitializeComponent();
           BindingContext = viewModel;
           client= selected_client;
            map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(10)));

           //Just a test pin
           var pin = new Pin()
           {
               Position = new Position(37, -122),
               Label = "Some Pin!"
           };
           map.Pins.Add(pin);
           Content = map;


       }
       protected override void OnAppearing()
       {
           base.OnAppearing();
           if (viewModel.CoordinateParnertPins.Count == 0)
           {
               viewModel.CommandGetCoordinatePins.Execute(client);

           }
       }
}
```

I'm trying to use MVVM pattern . When command execute i get a list of pins. My question is how to add the pins to the map? If define in the ClientMap() constructor the list of pins is empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use Messaging Center to send message when get the list of pin .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i get the list from my API and have all pins in viewModel.ClietnPinsList  but because request is async dont add pins to the map

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT the first code:
``` MessagingCenter.Send<Object, List<Position>>(this, "addPins", PinList);``` I add in the async Task function after add all Pins in the list?

Comment: Yes , you are right .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### in ViewModel

invoke the following code after you get the list of pins

```
 MessagingCenter.Send<Object, List<Position>>(this, "addPins", PinList); // PinList is type of List<Position>
```

#### in Content Page

```
public ClientMap(Client selected_client)
{
   //...
   map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(10)));

   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, List<Position>>(this, "addPins", (args,list) => {
            
     foreach(Position position in list)
     {
       map.Pins.Add(position);
     }
   });
  Content = map;
}
```